# What are the best practices to be followed in deployment of asp.net web application & WCF service in IIS 7?

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, asp.net-development-serv

Anybody can provide me the best practices to be followed in deployment of asp.net web application  & WCF service in IIS 7 regarding the **IIS 7 configuration settings , Security setting, application access level settings**..

Comment: You might get better answers to these questions from http://serverfault.com/ as the sys admin community is, generally, more aware of the implications of things like IIS configuration =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this help?  [IIS Security](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/88/configuring-security/). Where possible you should only install / enable the IIS features that you intend to use.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your situation.

I always publish my solution to a folder, zip it, ftp it to my server.
On the server (using RemoteDesktop) i backup the running version (makes me feel safe & secure)  and delete all the files, except web.config. I unzip the file i sent and copy all the files, except web.config. If i made changes to web.config i adjust it manually.

This works for me because i have a shitty internet connection. If it were faster i'd do it differently.

Comment: Thanks Jeroen, i mean to say that, specifically security settings for IIS and our web application.

Comment: It didn't say that when i answered. Be sure to ask a complete question the first time. If you ask a general question you get a general answer.